# Python loop not moving to next file

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to traverse a directory, searching for all files containing the word 'Summary' in it's title. Once the file is found, I want to open the file and retrieve the lines with 'Audit Name' and 'Verified Hits' present. Also, retrieved the dirpath of the file.

My current codes searches a directory with 3 Summary files. Finds the dirpath and filenames, but only gets the contents from the first file, and prints that information three times.

```
import os
data_dir = "<dir with data>"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(data_dir):
    for name in filenames:
        if 'Summary' in name:
            ofile = open(name, "r+")
            lines = ofile.readlines()
            ofile.close()
            for line in lines:
                if 'Audit Name:' in line:
                    audit_name = line
                if 'Verified Hits' in line:
                    verified_hits = line
            print(audit_name + verified_hits)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the two files not yielding a result contain the required lines? I suggest that you reset audit_name and verified_hits at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
ofile = open(name, "r+")
```

Name is just the filename, and doesn't include the path. So you're opening the same path 3 times.

Try

```
ofile = open(os.path.join(dirpath, name), "r+")
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought OP seemed to say that the files are in the same directory.

Comment: I took it as being in that directory or a subdirectory. Otherwise I'm not sure why he'd use `os.walk`, but you might be right.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you have found the problem.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up anyway, just in case for OP

Comment: The 'os.path.join' module was exactly what I needed. Thank you for the feedback.